# single input opamp vs dual input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, cascode

Could anyone please refresh my memory regarding op-amps? I am reading [this](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-10) article about Cascodes op-amps to refresh my memory about them - and I see a single input into each op-amp: 
[image]

Is it assumed that both the op-amp's inputs are tied together?
[image]

**Update**
Is it like that:
[image]

Comment: Think about what would happenmif you shorted both inputs of an opAmp together. ... I don't really think that would accomplish much.

Comment: I know, ideally it will be nothing. So diagram wise, there are two images of an op-amp while its actually description of a single one with seperate inputs?

Comment: Actually, reading the article, it looks like that representative diagram is of single-transistor amplifier stages, rather than opAmps. Also, I noticed that the author used '8' instead of 'infinity' for an ideal value of R(in), so other things in the text may be less than 100% reliable.

Comment: I updated the question with another diagram - should I think about Cascodes that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **must** look at that diagram as opAmp based (which the text of the article **clearly** states that they are intended to represent **single transistor amplifiers** instead), then they'd be wired something like this:

[image]